# Oracle sql count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below information in table and want to retrive the count if difference between two dates is >= 1.

```
Id  testdate  exdate    
1   20120502  20120501  --> This should included, because diff is 1    
2   20120601  20120601  --> This should not included, because diff is 0    
3   20120704  20120703  --> This should included, because diff is 1    
4   20120803  20120802  --> This should included, because diff is 1
```

Based on the above data, my select count should return 3.

I am trying the following, but it's not giving any results:

```
select count(to_char(testdate,'YYYYMMDD')-to_char(exdate,'YYYYMMDD')) from test ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(*)
  from my_table
 where testdate <> exdate
```

You really should convert those to a `date` data-type though... it saves a lot of problems in the long run.

Your query will give you results. It will return 4. It gives you results because as long as the result of `testdate - exdate` is not null it will return a value for that row.

However, as you're not using dates Oracle will most probably convert those to numbers, which won't help for date comparisons should you do that in the future.

```
20120901 - 20120831 = 70 -- not 1
```

---

Okay, from your comment:

> Working with ,if i use down voteaccept select count(*) from test where
>   to_char((testdate,'YYYYMMDD') - to_char(exdate,'YYYYMMDD')) >= 1; .But
>   count is one of the column.how to retrive above select statement as
>   one of the column

you're trying something completely different.

Your dates are actually dates; it's helpful to post this. You're looking for an [analytic function](http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html), specifically `count()`.

```
select a.*, count(*) over ( partition by 1 ) as ct
  from my_table a
 where trunc(exdate) <> trunc(testdate)
```

Note the [`trunc`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) function, which, without additional parameters will remove the time portion of the date this enabling a direct comparison without resorting to converting the date to a character.

Comment: :I want the count only when difference between 2 dates is >=1.

Comment: If the dates aren't equal then by definition the difference is greater or equal to 1 as they don't have a time component.

Comment: :Getting error ,non numeric charcter was found where numeric expected

Comment: What is the _data type_ of your columns?

Comment: Working with ,if i use 

down voteaccept
 

select count(*) 
   from test 
  where to_char((testdate,'YYYYMMDD') - to_char(exdate,'YYYYMMDD')) >= 1; .But count is one of the column.how to retrive above select statement as one of the column

Comment: i want above select statement in select clause,like select id,above count stement from test

Comment: Thanks Ben,i ma getting correct results if i am deducting process date from trade date

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
   from test
  where to_date(testdate,'YYYYMMDD') - to_date(exdate,'YYYYMMDD') >= 1;
```

or

```
select count(*)
   from test
  where to_date(testdate,'YYYYMMDD') <> to_date(exdate,'YYYYMMDD');
```

Looking at `testdate` and `exdate` it looks more like the columns are `VARCHAR` type so you would require apropriate date conversion.

Comment: Getting error ,non numeric charcter was found where numeric expected

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle if the type is date you can calculate with them. 1 equal 1 day. 1/24 equals 1 hour.

Your case is rather easy because you could even compare the strings.

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM test
 WHERE testdate <> exdate
```

But it sounds like you want to be able to be variable, so you rather convert them to a date and then you can do

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM test
 WHERE to_date(testdate,'YYYYMMDD')-to_date(exdate,'YYYYMMDD') >= 1
```

I am not sure what you want if testdate minus exdate is -1 or more because the exdate is after testdate. Then you can work with `ABS`

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM test
 WHERE ABS(to_date(testdate,'YYYYMMDD')-to_date(exdate,'YYYYMMDD')) >= 1
```

Comment: Getting error ,non numeric charcter was found where numeric expected.

Comment: This happens when the character string is not a date. In that case you cannot use to_date. You need to implement an is_date function which returns null instead of an error. This link shows how http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:890580198758